# Чем класс Object отличается от других родительских классов?

Tags: java, объекты, наследование

Есть классы:

```
class Monster{ //Родительский класс


        public void eat(){
            System.out.println("Есть всё!");
        }

     }

    public class Smm extends Monster {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Monster[] monster  = new Monster[3];
            monster[0]=new Monster();
            monster[1]=new Smm();
            monster[2]=new Vurdalak();
            for (int i=0; i<monster.length;i++){
                monster[i].eat();
            }
        }
        public void eat(){
            System.out.println("Никто не знает, что я ем!");
        }

        }


    public class Vurdalak extends Monster {
        public void eat(){
            System.out.println("Есть мясо!");
        }
    }
```

После выполнения данной программы, получаем следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но почему, если в качестве родительского класса использовать класс Objekt, ничего не получиться?

Comment: Что именно значит "ничего не получиться"?

Comment: Я бы сказал, что класс `Object` отличается от других классов только набором методов, и необходимо помнить, что неявно Вы всегда наследуетесь от класса `Object`, а значит всегда можете использовать его методы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому, что Objekt ничего не знает о методе eat() - в Object просто нет этого метода, а в родительском классе Monster он есть, как и в классах потомках